# When (in Java) a static method and an instance method with the same name exist in different classes, I cannot access the method

Tags: java, static-methods

First, please take a look at the following code.

```
package test;

class c_hi {
    public static void method_hi(){
        System.out.println("hi");
    }
}

class c_bye {
    public void method_hi(){
        System.out.println("bye");
    }
}

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        c_hi.method_hi();
        c_bye c_hi = new c_bye();
        c_hi.method_hi();
    }
}
```

I've been using Java for several years, and I understand the general rules for naming class names and variable names.

However, I got a very interesting question. If the name of the reference variable of the "c_bye" class is "c_hi" (a class named "c_hi" already exists),

I can't access "method_hi" of class "c_hi" from inside class "test".

Of course, I know that this problem can be prevented or circumvented by not overlapping class names and variable names, package separation, and FQCN etc.

Apart from the usual way of avoiding duplicate names, is there a more grammatical way to solve this problem? Please tell me your opinion. (Or, I would appreciate any documentation, links, or other questions on Stack Overflow that I can refer to.)

This code works the same for both JDK versions 8 and 15.

Comment: The most obvious is test.c_hi.method_hi();

Comment: If you used standard Java naming conventions, it would be `class C_hi...` and `class C_bye...` and `C_bye c_hi = new C_bye();`. Then there would be no confusion.

Comment: @JimGarrison Exactly. That is what naming conventions and compilers' "name shadowing" warnings are all about. As mnesarco already pointed out, use the more qualified name to resolve this "problem". In this case, it would be the static access. Same thing is dynamic access: if you're inside an inner class CInner that is inside the outer class COuter, and you wanna access COuter's methods/members from CInner: you type `COuter.this.methodName()`. Or, if there are still name shadowing problems, include the full package names.

Comment: Well, there shouldn't be an under bar in Java names.  On the OP's question: [variable hiding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html) is a thing in Java.  Plan appropriately.

Comment: Full qualification "solves" the problem, but doesn't fix the bad code.  There's no reason to write code like this.

Comment: What immediately strikes me at a glance: if you've been using Java for years, now, why do you exemplify with such a horrible naming? you can reproduce this with a normal JavaNamingConventions. Naming is not a game.. it's actually one of the most serious aspects of programming.

Comment: Thank you all. This question is not mine, I found it in another community. I think this question was probably asked by someone new to Java.

And, at first, I thought of an answer similar to what most of you were talking about.

But I thought that answering "It's just a matter of names of classes, methods, and variables" might not be the definitive answer for someone new to Java programming.

So I've posted a question here, where I can find out the fastest reasonable solution.

Thank you all for giving good comments. I will refer to your comments and various links below.

Answer (score 6):

This should "fix" the problem:

```
    test.c_hi.method_hi();  // Using the fully qualified class name.
```

However, the *correct* solution would be:

1. Don't ignore Java style rules.  The rules say Java method name should start with a lowercase letter, and a class name should start with an uppercase letter.
2. Avoid using the same name for a static method and an instance method.

   (You actually can't do this in some cases.  For example, if `c_bye` extends `c_hi` then you get a compilation error about an instance method not being allowed to override a static method.)
3. Don't attempt to call a static method using an instance variable.  Use the class name.  (Which *cannot* be confused with a variable name if you follow the style rules!)

   It is legal Java to do that, but it tends to fool the reader into thinking that the method is an instance method and/or that there is dynamic dispatching of static methods happening.

For what it is worth the rules for name resolution are fully specified in the JLS.  (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66056069/139985) for the JLS text and reference.) The implications are a bit complicated for *edge cases* like the one you are talking about, but the name resolution rules are not Java version specific, AFAIK.

Java is not designed to "play nice" when people willfully ignore the style rules.

Answer (score 2):

The Java Language Specification deals with that. here the first paragraph of JLS 6.4.2 Obscuring:

> A simple name may occur in contexts where it may potentially be interpreted as the name of a variable, a type, or a package. In these situations, the rules of [§6.5.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.5.2) specify that a variable will be chosen in preference to a type, and that a type will be chosen in preference to a package. Thus, it is may sometimes be impossible to refer to a type or package via its simple name, even though its declaration is in scope and not shadowed. We say that such a declaration is obscured.

As you already mentioned, FQN must be used instead of the simple name.